# CKEditor5 Insert Text without breaking current element

Tags: ckeditor5

I have the following code to insert Text at current position:

```
editor.model.change( writer => {
                    editor.model.insertContent( writer.createText('[Insert]') );
                });
```

This works fine in most case like inserting inside a paragraph or headline. 
Example given:

Before:

```
<h2>Sample</h2>
```

After insertion:

```
<h2>Samp[Insert]le</h2>
```

But if the text is preformatted for example with a custom font size it breaks the html element:

Before:

```
<p><span class="text-huge">Sample formatted text</span></p>
```

After insertion:

```
<p><span class="text-huge">Sample fo</span>[Insert]<span class="text-huge">rmatted text</span></p>
```

Notice, that the  Element is split up and the text is inserted without applying the custom styles. The [Insert] is set between two spans...

How can I Insert a text directly without modifying html structure?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This happens because created text node has no attributes set. To do this you need to [get current selection's attributes](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_model_documentselection-DocumentSelection.html#function-getAttributes) and pass it to the [`writer.createText()`](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_model_writer-Writer.html#function-createText) method. Then the created text node will have those attributes:

```js
const model = editor.model;

model.change( writer => {
    const currentAttributes = model.document.selection.getAttributes();

    model.insertContent( writer.createText( '[Foo]', currentAttributes ) );
} );
```

Alternatively you can use [`writer.insertText()`](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_model_writer-Writer.html#function-insertText) method if you're inserting text:

```js
editor.model.change( writer => {
    const selection = editor.model.document.selection;

    const currentAttributes = selection.getAttributes();
    const insertPosition = selection.focus;

    writer.insertText( '[Foo]', currentAttributes, insertPosition );
} );
```

Comment: Thanks for the api reference, my answer was there ;)

Comment: I'm using angular, I don't see this "model" attribute anywhere on the editor. where is this coming from?

Comment: The `model` is a property of the `editor` object [docs](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_core_editor_editor-Editor.html#member-model). To access the editor instance checkout [angular docs in CKEditor 5 docs](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/installation/frameworks/angular.html#accessing-the-editor-instance).